# React Native - How to pass the Image from the other Component without using React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The goal is to pass the State of the Photos from my `CameraRoll.js` (Modal) to `EventCreator.js`(Modal) without using the React Redux. I'm using React Native Navigation V1.

I'm wondering maybe it is possible state of `photos: []` become props? Just don't know how to do it. Need help, thank you guys!

Here are my codes:

CameraRoll.js:

```
state = {
  photos: [],
  index: null,
  pickedImage: null
}

getPhotos = () => {
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
  first: 200,
  assetType: 'All'
})
.then(res => {
  this.setState({ 
    photos: res.edges,
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Error image: ' + err);
});
};

render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} style={styles.image}/>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {this.state.photos.map((photos, index) => {
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight 
              style={{opacity: index === this.state.index ? .5 : 1}}
              onPress={() => this.setState({pickedImage: photos.node.image.uri})}
              key={index}
              underlayColor='transparent'
            >
              <Image
                style={{width: width / 3, height: width /3}}
                source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
                resizeMode='cover'
              />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
}
```

EventCreator.js:

```
render(){
 return(
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <EventInput
          titleOnChangeText={this.eventNameChangedHandler}
          descriptionOnChangeText={this.eventDescriptionChangedHandler}
          titleEvent={this.state.controls.eventName}
          descriptionEvent={this.state.controls.eventDescription}
        />
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={"I want to pass the image here from CameraRoll.js"}
          resizeMode='contain'
        />
      </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: In which class do you call EventCreator (I mean from the render)?

Comment: From it's own component. I'll edit it again for you to understand well.

Comment: I mean in which class did you put the tag `<EventCreator .... />`

Comment: In the CameraRoll.js, when I press the button it will navigate to EventCreator.js

Comment: It is simple just pass the image url as param when u do routing.

Comment: How? Sorry I just have little knowledge about React.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean this:

```
onPress={() => this.setState({pickedImage: photos.node.image.uri})}
```

it just change the state value. What you should do is put an if statement on the return of cameraRoll.js:

```
private onPress = (img) => {
    this.props.onImagePicked(img)
}
render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} style={styles.image}/>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {this.state.photos.map((photos, index) => {
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight 
              style={{opacity: index === this.state.index ? .5 : 1}}
              onPress={() => this.onPress(photos.node.image.uri))}
              key={index}
              underlayColor='transparent'
            >
              <Image
                style={{width: width / 3, height: width /3}}
                source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
                resizeMode='cover'
              />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
}
```

And in EventCreator.js:

```
constructor(){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pickedImg: undefined
    }
}

private onImagePicked = (newImg) => {
    this.setState({
        pickedImg: newImg
    })
}

render(){
 return(
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <EventInput
          titleOnChangeText={this.eventNameChangedHandler}
          descriptionOnChangeText={this.eventDescriptionChangedHandler}
          titleEvent={this.state.controls.eventName}
          descriptionEvent={this.state.controls.eventDescription}
        />
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={this.props.source}
          resizeMode='contain'
        />
      <CameraRoll props={...} onImagePicked={this.onImagePicked}/>
      </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: That is not what I mean. Maybe I limit my explanation, uhm, I have 2 screens, the CameraRoll.js and the EventCreator.js. This is what I want, what Image I choose in CameraRoll.js Screen(Modal rnnv1), I want to show it in the EventCreator.js Screen (Modal rnnv1)

Comment: So I think that you call EventCreator from a parent component. what you can do is "set" as parent component EventCreator for CameraRoll, create a function on EventCreator that change his own state and pass this function as props to CameraRoll. When you choose the new image call this function passing the new image and it will change the state on EventCreator. I don't know if the logic to set EventCreator as parent component of CameraRoll is right, but I think is the only method you can use if you don't want to use redux

Comment: Can you edit your answer? Just don't understand well.

Comment: What I meant  was that you can set EventCreator as parent component for CameraRoll (So call <CameraRoll props={...} /> from EventCreator's render), create a function on EventCreator that change its own state and pass this function as props on CameraRoll.

Comment: Ow yea, I already get it. But the problem, in CameraRoll.js there's a ScrollView of Images from the Phone's Gallery, so if I use <CameraRoll /> in EventCreator.js theScrollView of Images will be display too instead of only just one Image that is chosen from the CameraRoll.js

Comment: So just put an if statement that check if an image has been picked (through the state) and in this case doesn't render the ScrollView

Comment: Can I ask why there is a `private`?

Comment: because it is a class and with private I'm "saying" that this method can't be called like a public method

Comment: I think what your trying to do is not possible because of the node.image.uri. Have you tried the code?